# Get specific string from terminal and print to txt file

Tags: macos, terminal

I've got very noobish question: is there any way to setup script which checks output in OSX terminal for specific string, and then sends whole line containing this string to text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)?

```
some-command | grep 'searchstring' >> Foobar.txt
```